# Spring Boot and MongoDB unknown operator: $last

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to execute simpliest aggregation operation possible with $group:

```
{ "_id" : "$sensor", "lastTimestamp" : { "$last" : "$timestamp"}}
```

Here are sample records:

```
sensor: A
timestamp: 3:27:14
value: 3.29

sensor: A
timestamp: 4:27:14
value: 5.29
```

If I execute query inside MongoDB Compass, then it returns valid result:

```
_id: "A"
lastTimestamp: 4:27:14
```

If I execute it as a custom query for Spring Data Reposirory, e.g.

```
public interface EventDataProvider extends MongoRepository<Event, String> {

    @Query("{ \"_id\" : \"$sensor\", \"lastTimestamp\" : { \"$last\" : \"$timestamp\"}}")
    List<Object> customQuery();
}
```

then I get exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'unknown operator: $last' on server localhost:27017
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:735) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:725) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:463) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
```

Can you please advise how to make custom query working?

Thanks

Comment: You have to use [@Aggregation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.aggregation) annotation _instead of_ the `@Query` annotation, as you are trying to perform a `$group` Aggregation operation.

Comment: @prasad_ can you move your comment to answer area please, so I can mark it as correct answer? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run an aggregation group query using the Spring repository object, you have to use the [@Aggregation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Aggregation.html) instead of the `@Query`.

Define the repository and run from the Spring Boot application:

```
@Repository
public interface SensorRepository extends MongoReppsitory<Sensor, String> {

    @Aggregation("{ $group : { _id : $sensor, lastTimestamp: { $last : $timestamp } } }")
    List<SensorAggregate> groupBySensors();
}
```

Run the aggregation on the `sensor` collection:

```
@Autowired
private SensorRepository repos;
// ...
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    List<SensorAggregate> list = repos.groupBySensors();
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

POJO classes `Sensor` and `SensorAggregate`:

```
public class Sensor {

    private String id;
    private String sensor;
    private String timestamp;
    private double value;

    public Sensor(String id, String sensor, String timestamp, double value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sensor = sensor;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

     public String getSensor() {
         return sensor;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return sensor + ", " + timestamp;
    }
} 


public class SensorAggregate {

    private @Id String sensor;                                                     
    private String lastTimestamp;

    public PersonAggregate(String sensor, String lastTimestamp) {
        this.sensor = sensor;
        this.lastTimestamp = lastTimestamp;
    }

     public String getSensor() {
         return sensor;
    }

    public String getLastTimestamp() {
        return lastTimestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return sensor + ", " + lastTimestamp;
    }
}
```